# WPF combie 3 objects into a area button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

first of all I apologize for my English.

I am making a simple C# WPF app. I've added an ellipse,label1,label2 onto my MainWindow.xaml.

I want to make these 3 objects (ellipse,label1,label2) into a button. I want this button to load my second wpf page, called "Size". As I understand it should be an area button. I've tried to use "border" (from WPF controls) with "MouseDown" (from event handler) but the effect is not that good. Any tips? What should I do?

The code I've used for event handler is:

```
   private void Border_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Size secondPage = new Size();
        secondPage.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redefine button style, You can do it using ControlTemplate. Here is example how to write reusable style that redefines button.

I have added also an example how to implement color change on IsPressed event.

```
<Window x:Class="ColorTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonBackground" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFD9EDFF" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFC0DEFF" Offset="0.445"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFAFD1F8" Offset="0.53"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <Style x:Key="SimpleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border Background="{StaticResource ButtonBackground}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            <Border x:Name="BorderPressed"  Opacity="0" Background="Blue" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            <Label Name="label1" Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Label>
                            <Label Name="label2"  Content="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Label>
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="MainContent" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderPressed" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderPressed" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" Name="button1" Width="75" Style="{StaticResource SimpleButtonStyle}" Click="button1_Click"/>
</DockPanel>
```